# Applying "is" operator to method group: why compiler allows it?

Tags: c#, method-group

Consider the following code:

```
var result = IDisposable.Dispose is object; //result equals false
```

It was surprise for me(and to my [colleague](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1351097/szkarlen) that actually drew my attention to it) that this code is compiled.

First my thought was that `IDisposable.Dispose` is somehow converted to a compatible `delegate`. But then result must be `true` since `delegate` is compartible with `object`, of course.

Looking into the specification I found that method groups have special treating by the compiler(in the context of *is* operation):

> If E is a method group ... the result is false.

Purely out of curiosity, why is it in the spec? Why does the compiler allow it? Why not to throw compile-time error (like for anonymous functions, for instance)?

UPDATE:

- It compiled for me in VS2013 (12.0.21005.1) and .NET 4.5/4.5.1;
- *piojo* let us know that this code is NOT compiled in Mono(I can't check it myself);
- It is NOT compiled for *leppie* in VS2015(4.5 or 3.5);
- NOT compiled under VS2013 / 12.0.30501.00 update 2, .NET 4.5.2 target(*caramiriel*);

Comment: Curiously, it actually doesn't compile on Mono. (At least, not my version.)

Comment: @piojo, thank you. I updated question with your note.

Comment: Does not compile for me on 4.5 or 3.5 in VS2015: `error CS0837: The first operand of an 'is' or 'as' operator may not be a lambda expression, anonymous method, or method group.`

Comment: In VS2010, it is only a warning: `warning CS0184: The given expression is never of the provided ('object') type`

Comment: Compiler even puts a `nop` and `0` (i4) on the stack in debug-mode, so it's not even ending up in the resulting assembly (VS2013 / 12.0.30501.00 update 2, .NET 4.5.2 target).

Comment: In VS2013, it also gives a compiler error. I can only assume this was deemed a bug and the warning was changed to an error. I dont have VS2012 handy to test if this a warning or error.

Comment: Does compile on VS2013 and .Net 4.5.1.

Comment: It does compile on my end. I am using VS2012, .NET 4. I am only getting the warning: *The given expression is never of the provided ('object') type*

Comment: @Caramiriel: Same setup for VS2013 Update 2, targetting anything, compiler reports error.

Comment: Using ildasm on the .exe I only get: `.entrypoint .maxstack  8 ret`!

Comment: Related discussion by Jon Skeet back in 2006 on the matter: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7f6ac5f0-1c31-46c5-b965-99438fe374b8/cs0184-should-be-a-compile-error?forum=csharplanguage Note that method groups are not mentioned in the related MSDN document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384251%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @leppie Does 2015 come with an updated spec that no longer says it should evaluate to false?

Comment: you don't have to edit in all the individual comments in to your question. people can read the comments.

Comment: @Rawling: I have no idea. We should summon the language lawyers ;p

Comment: They targetted a `method group` specifically in the specs of the `is` operator? Wow. I wouldn't be suprised by a delegate, but a method group? I always thought `method groups` are only a tiny entity related to initialization of delegates. Why would anyone try to IS a MG? Please, can anyone enlighten me? One use case would be enough

Comment: [Roslyn](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Operators.cs,2562) doesn't provides many clues either, other than basically saying "it's in the spec"... although it does show the [switch to an error](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Operators.cs,2529)

Comment: I believe it's clearly a bug. It can't be converted to any delegate type since you didn't specify any. the method signature might be compatible with more than one delegate. So..

Comment: It's not just specifically called out once in the spec; section 7.1 (Expression classifications) also explicitly calls out the three places where method groups are valid - including as the left hand side of an `is` - so it definitely looks *deliberate*.

Comment: @Rhumborl weird that they haven't taken out the warning case now that the error case is in place. Also, I wish I could see whtat `DevDiv #864740` was :D

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ,Rawling,well then clearly that spec is not up to date.Since it gives this compiler error on VS 2015 Preview, as stated in previous comments: _error CS0837: The first operand of an 'is' or 'as' operator may not be a lambda expression, anonymous method, or method group._

Comment: @Selman22 Is there a C# 6.0 spec published yet? (BTW it's not *not up to date*, it's the *C# 5.0* spec. It's not going to go out of date.)

Comment: @Rawling yes, it's C#5.0 spec. when the new spec is published it will go out of date.

Comment: I can't find a 2.0 spec around at the moment; the 1.1 language spec doesn't allow this construct, but by version 3.0 it's been added - so it was added to the spec as part of either 2.0 or 3.0.

Comment: @Selman22 - no, it will not go out of date. If, in ten years time, you want to construct a compiler that parses C# 5.0, that will be the spec to follow.